# iOS Game Controller framework : How to use "startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler"

Tags: ios, frameworks, gamecontroller

When game controller be paired from system setting, all is fine.

But I want to discover & pair game controller in my app.

Actually I found that it seems feasible by Apple's docs.
[doc link : Discovering and Connecting to Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/DiscoveringControllers/DiscoveringControllers.html).

I have a game controller which is in pairing...

But I found the log of function "`startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler`" never be shown.

Seems the behavior does not conform.

I call "`startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler`" when app load...

I also call "`stopWirelessControllerDiscovery`", but still same.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 ...

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gameControllerDidConnect:) name:GCControllerDidConnectNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gameControllerDidDisconnect:) name:GCControllerDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

 [GCController startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Finished finding controllers");
    [self completionWirelessControllerDiscovery];
 }];

 ...
}

- (void)completionWirelessControllerDiscovery {
    if (isDebug) {
        NSLog(@"%s-%d", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    }
}
```

Someone has experiences on this?

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that it does not work for pairing a controller - I have always had to pair my game controllers directly to the device.  I've been developing a wrapper around GCController, so I've tested about 5 different MFi controllers with no luck getting GCController to manage the pairing process.